# ¿Cómo contar cuantos números negativos hay en un array?

Tags: c#, array

Ahora mismo estoy intentando crear un vector y que este me cuente como tal cuantas veces aparecen los numeros negativos, ya he intentado usar contador e imprimir ese valor, pero nada, se queda blanco (y ya me asegure que la funcion estuviera asignada al boton.

Aqui el script:

```
int[] numero = new int[10];
        int i;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out i))
            numero[0] = i;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out i))
            numero[1] = i;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out i))
            numero[2] = i;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out i))
            numero[3] = i;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out i))
            numero[4] = i;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox6.Text, out i))
            numero[5] = i;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox7.Text, out i))
            numero[6] = i;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out i))
            numero[7] = i;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox9.Text, out i))
            numero[8] = i;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox10.Text, out i))
            numero[9] = i;

        for (i = 0; i < numero.Length; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(numero[i]);


        }

        int negativo = 0;


        if (numero[i] < 0)
        {
            negativo++;
        }




        textBox11.Text = negativo.ToString();
```

Comment: compañero, te comento primero que en tu script no hay ningún número que cumpla con la condición de negativo dentro de tu array conforme vas haciendo push, segundo creo que es un tema de scope o ámbito ya que el IF donde estás verificando si alguna de las posiciones es negativa está fuera del ciclo que recorre el array. Verifica, corrige y nos comentas. Cualquier adicional a la orden. Saludos cordiales

Answer (score 1):

No te está contando nada porque has declarado el `if(numero[i] < 0)` fuera del bucle `for`.

Intenta esto:

```
int negativo = 0;
for (i = 0; i < numero.Length; i++){
    listBox1.Items.Add(numero[i]);
    if (numero[i] < 0){
    negativo++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eso me ayudo, gracias, me has salvado :)

Comment: Si te ha servido la respuesta, por favor, márcala como aceptada. (icono ✓ a la izquierda de la respuesta)

Answer (score 1):

Partiendo de la base que `numero` es un array, con Linq se puede hacer:

Primero hacer el using

```
using System.Linq;
```

y este metodo hace ese calculo

```
numero.Count(n => n < 0);
```

Solo esa linea debería solucionarlo